# Rstudio shiny renderDataTable headers multi line?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have a `renderDataTable` table in Rstudio Shiny that I build with some columns I want to have the header going multi-line, so that a long header string takes a small amount of horizontal space. E.g.:

My long header column is called `a_very_long_header` in my data.frame, and with the `colnames` trick below I can turn it into `a-very-long-header`, which then turns into an ugly multi-line header:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$dt <- renderDataTable({
  data =     data.frame(a_very_long_header=rnorm(10),a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c=rnorm(10),d=rnorm(10),e=rnorm(10),f=rnorm(10),g=rnorm(10),h=rnorm(10),i=rnorm(10),j=rnorm(10),k=rnorm(10),a1=rnorm(10),b1=rnorm(10),c1=rnorm(10),d1=rnorm(10),e1=rnorm(10),f1=rnorm(10),g1=rnorm(10),h1=rnorm(10),i1=rnorm(10),j1=rnorm(10),k1=rnorm(10))
  colnames(data) = c("a-very-long-header","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","u","j","k","a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1","g1","h1","u1","j1","k1")
    return(data)
   })
})


shinyUI(navbarPage("Foo", id="page", collapsable=TRUE, inverse=FALSE,
   tabPanel("Bar",
       dataTableOutput("dt")
      )
   )
)
```

[image]

Is there a more elegant way to turn `a_very_long_header` into `a very long header` so that it prints the header in multi-line?

Comment: Just an update to jdharrison's post. You now need to add escape = FALSE in order to recognize HTML in DT table. [Shiny DT Documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HTML`

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$dt <- renderDataTable({
    data =     data.frame(a_very_long_header=rnorm(10),a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c=rnorm(10),d=rnorm(10),e=rnorm(10),f=rnorm(10),g=rnorm(10),h=rnorm(10),i=rnorm(10),j=rnorm(10),k=rnorm(10),a1=rnorm(10),b1=rnorm(10),c1=rnorm(10),d1=rnorm(10),e1=rnorm(10),f1=rnorm(10),g1=rnorm(10),h1=rnorm(10),i1=rnorm(10),j1=rnorm(10),k1=rnorm(10))
    colnames(data) = c("a very<br>long header","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","u","j","k","a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1","g1","h1","u1","j1","k1")
    return(data)
  })
}
, ui = navbarPage("Foo", id="page", collapsable=TRUE, inverse=FALSE,
                   tabPanel("Bar",
                            dataTableOutput("dt")
                   )
)
)
)
```

[image]

Comment: weird, in my case, if I do `colnames(data) = chartr("-","<br>",colnames(data))`, I can only see the first of the tokens displayed in the header...