# datatables headerCallback acess all css properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have header with some css style inside html. When I call header callback and try to get css properties, I get just width and the rest shows undefined

```
  "headerCallback": function( thead, data, start, end, display ) {
  
    console.log($($(thead).find('th').eq(1)).css('left'))
  

  },
```

but in browser console when I do just `console.log($($(thead).find('th').eq(1)))` I see that style attribute has more properties

[image]

How can I access them?

I also tried `$($(thead).find('th').eq(1)).attr("style")` but still shows only first property (width)

edit: here is extracted html from that thead

```
<tr><th class="center-text dt-checkboxes-cell dt-checkboxes-select-all sorting_disabled dtfc-fixed-left" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custom_list_details" rowspan="1" colspan="1" data-col="0" data-column-index="0" style="width: 13px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); left: 0px; position: sticky;" aria-label=""><input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"></th><th class="min-width-200px sorting sorting_asc dtfc-fixed-left" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custom_list_details" rowspan="1" colspan="1" data-column-index="1" style="width: 200px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); left: 49.2333px; position: sticky;" aria-label="
      Company name
    : activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">
      Company name
    </th>
    </tr>
```

edit2:
here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fpvc9qb/) with the problem
Company name has some left style property, but code shows "auto"

Comment: Without HTML, it's impossible to tell exactly what you've done wrong.  Note that `.eq(n)` is 0-based, so `.eq(1)` is the *second* column.      Given some guess at the HTML, your [code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/90h1cLnx/)

Comment: It's unclear from [headerCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/headerCallback) whether the callback is before or after it's been rendered - looks like (and should be) after it's been built, but maybe not before rendered - ie the `thead` parameter may be an in-memory version not yet rendered.

Comment: @freedomn-m headerCallback should return rendered..I tried to get css property in drawCallback and that always returns 0, even for width. And as I do console.log of that thead and shows in console that style contains left property, I assume it should be there

Comment: Can you provide a sample datatable (doesn't need to be your exact code, just enough to *demonstrate* the issue)?   The [SO datatables wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) has a snippet starter kit.  **Edit** including your `th` from your edit - it still works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/90h1cLnx/1/  It's not clear why it's not working for you.

Comment: @freedomn-m I updated jsfiddle to keep simple html and let datatable to generate the properties

Comment: Inspecting the HTML at the time of `headerCallback` shows that it only has `width` style at that time https://jsfiddle.net/av1t7cp3/1/ - It looks like datatables calculates additional details such as `left` after the `headerCallback` has completed.

Comment: it looks like only way how to do that was to add 1 second delay into header callback

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?  Maybe it's an XY Problem and there's another way to do what your end-goal is.

Comment: I was trying to fix this issue...it looks that is still an issue in datatables so this workaround is ok for me :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71753665/datatables-fixed-columns-with-duplicated-header-for-column-filtering-not-fixed/71780598#71780598