# datatables fixed columns with duplicated header for column filtering not fixed

Tags: javascript, datatables

I duplicated my thead row for custom column search according [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html)

Problem is that I have fixed columns 0 and 1 from left. When I perform scroll right, second row which contains input for column filter is moving but the rest of column is sticky.
As I see css, that tr element is missing sticky position as the rest of fixed columns.

How to fix it?

this is my code

```
 $('#custom_list_details thead tr').clone(false)
        .addClass('head_filters')
        .appendTo('#custom_list_details thead');
      


 custom_list_details_table= $('#custom_list_details').DataTable({
    'order': [[1, 'asc']],
    "orderCellsTop": true,
    'fixedColumns': {
        'left': 2
    },
    "select":true,
    "keys": {
            "columns": ':not(:first-child)',
            "focus": ':eq(2)',
            "blurable": false

        },
    'colReorder': {
        'fixedColumnsLeft': 2
    },
    "ajax": '/customlist_table/'+$custom_list_id+'.json',

    "processing": true,
    'dom': 'lfr<"pull-right"B>tip',
    'buttons': [
    {"extend" : 'copyHtml5',"text":"Copy","className": 'btn btn-default btn-xs'},
    {"extend" : 'excelHtml5',"text": "XLS","className": 'btn btn-default btn-xs'},
    {"extend" : 'csvHtml5',"text": "CSV","className": 'btn btn-default btn-xs'},
    {
                text: 'Change table size',
                className: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs table-size-btn',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    if ($('#custom_list_details').hasClass('compact') && $('#custom_list_details').hasClass('smaller-table-font'))
                      { $('#custom_list_details').removeClass('compact smaller-table-font')}
                    else { $('#custom_list_details').addClass('compact smaller-table-font')}


                }
            }

   ],
   "columnDefs": [
   {
         'targets': 0,
         'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
         }
          
      }    
      
  ],
  "autoWidth":false,
 "columns": $columns,
 "pageLength": $user_profile_data.table_length,
 'lengthMenu': [
 [10, 50,100, -1],
 [10, 50,100, "All"]
 ],
   "columnDefs": [
   {
         'targets': 0,
         'className': 'center-text',
         'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
         }
      }
  ],
  initComplete: function ()
 {


$("th[data-column-index='1']").css("background-color","white")
$("th[data-column-index='0']").css("background-color","white") 


  var api = this.api();
   api
                .columns()
                .eq(0)
                .each(function (colIdx) {
                  if (colIdx > 0) {
                    // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                    var cell = $('.head_filters th').eq(
                        $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                    );
                                       
                    $(cell).html('<input class="form-control" style="width:100%" type="text" placeholder="" />');
 
                    // On every keypress in this input
                    $(
                        'input',
                        $('.head_filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                    )
                        .off('keyup change')
                        .on('keyup change', function (e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
 
                            // Get the search value
                            $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                            var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();
 
                            var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                            // Search the column for that value
                            api
                                .column(colIdx)
                                .search(
                                    this.value != ''
                                        ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                        : '',
                                    this.value != '',
                                    this.value == ''
                                )
                                .draw();
 
                            $(this)
                                .focus()[0]
                                .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                        });
                      }
                      else {
                         var cell = $('.head_filters th').eq(
                          $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                        );
                         $(cell).html('');

                      }
                });
   
    custom_list_details_table.columns.adjust() 
   //column search end   
  

     
    }
          });
```

[here is fiddle with the issue, input search is not fixed](http://live.datatables.net/kigotoga/1/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [DataTables docs about **FixedColums**](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/):

> **Additional complexity**
>
> It is important to state up front that utilising
> FixedColumns in your DataTable can **significantly increase the
> complexity of the table** and its use should not be undertaken lightly,
> particularly for complex tables.

Based on that, I don't really know if it's possible to create a second header row and make it *FixedColumns **compliant***, with the normal initialization options.

In Datatables' forum [there's a question](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/87413/#Comment_87413) (a bit old indeed, made in 2016) about a problem with **FixedColumns** extension and multiple header rows, where [the DataTable developer answers](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/87413/#Comment_87413):

> This ultimately is due to a limitation in DataTables in that ***you cannot construct complex headers using its initialisation options***.

Maybee this kind of issue is still here after 6 years? Don't know :)

That said, I managed to get it work with standard jQuery's DOM manipulation.

I added this `drawCallback()` in the initialization options, to have column widths recalculated on each draw:

```
drawCallback: function () {
    var api = this.api();
    api.columns.adjust();
}
```

After the table initialization and before the end of `$(document).ready()` I added a function to get the `left` CSS value from the fixed cells of the first header row and pass them to the corresponding cells in the second header row:

```
function cssAdjust(table) {
    // get the table header
    const header = table.table().header();

    // get the 'left' CSS declaration value for first_row-first_column 'th' cell
    const col1_CSS_left = $(header)
        .find('tr')
        .eq(0)      // first row
        .find('th')
        .eq(0)      // first column 
        .css('left');

    // apply the found value to the second_row-first_column 'th' cell
    $(header)
        .find('tr')
        .eq(1)      // second row
        .find('th')
        .eq(0)      // first column
        .css({ left: col1_CSS_left, position: 'sticky' });
    
    // get the 'left' CSS declaration value for first_row-second_column 'th' cell    
    const col2_CSS_left = $(header)
        .find('tr')
        .eq(0)      // first row
        .find('th')
        .eq(1)      // second column
        .css('left');
    
    // apply the found value to the second_row-second_column 'th' cell
    $(header)
        .find('tr')
        .eq(1)      // second row
        .find('th')
        .eq(1)      // second column
        .css({ left: col2_CSS_left, position: 'sticky' });

    table.draw(); // redraw the table
}
```

After that, always before the end of `$(document).ready()`, I added a `window.resize` listener, to avoid messing up widths of columns if the window is resized:

```
// add eventListener to window resize
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    cssAdjust(custom_list_details_table);
});

cssAdjust(custom_list_details_table); // <= I immediately call the function to have the fixed double header also in the first table draw;
```

Here is a **codepen** with the code:
https://codepen.io/cheesyman/pen/NWXXdPO

Comment: Thanks, I actually fixed that in headerCallback where I also copy css from first thead row but needed to wait one sec because headerCallback doesnt provide full css from top row